# Whether Python3.7.7 has cross module call instructions? I am writing an image processing project based on pyqt5

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5

I customized two modules, One is main.py, the other is algorithm.py, the main.py as program execution module. GUI is defined here.

look the code at `def menuEvent(self)` in main.py

`main.py`

```py
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from PyQt5 import QtGui
from PyQt5 import QtCore
import algorithm as alg

# pix = ""

class initUI(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(initUI, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.setupUI()

    def setupUI(self):
        self.resize(1000, 1000)
        self.setWindowTitle('ImgPro')
        self.setWindowIcon(QtGui.QIcon('web.png'))
        self.setFixedSize(self.width(), self.height())
        self.center()
        self.widgets()
        self.menubar()
        self.menuEvent()
        self.layouts()
        self.UIsetting()

    def center(self):
        qr = self.frameGeometry()
        cp = QtWidgets.QDesktopWidget().availableGeometry().center()
        qr.moveCenter(cp)
        self.move(qr.topLeft())

    def widgets(self):

        self.scaling = QtWidgets.QSlider(QtCore.Qt.Horizontal)
        self.rotation = QtWidgets.QSlider(QtCore.Qt.Horizontal)
        ...

    def menubar(self):
        self.menubar = self.menuBar()
        ...



    def menuEvent(self):
        self.open.triggered.connect(alg.FileAlgoriThms.OpenFile)
        self.save.triggered.connect(alg.FileAlgoriThms.SaveFile)
        self.quit.triggered.connect(alg.FileAlgoriThms.QuitProgram)

        self.midgray.triggered.connect(alg.GrayThms.MidGrayThm)
        self.light.triggered.connect(alg.GrayThms.LightThm)
        self.dark.triggered.connect(alg.GrayThms.DarkThm)
        self.binarization.triggered.connect(alg.GrayThms.BinarizationThm)

        self.gaussfilter.triggered.connect(alg.FilterThms.GaussFilterThm)
        self.medianfilter.triggered.connect(alg.FilterThms.MedianFilterThm)
        self.meanfilter.triggered.connect(alg.FilterThms.MeanFilterThm)

        self.twicecompress.triggered.connect(alg.CompressThms.TwiceCompressThm)
        self.quintupling.triggered.connect(alg.CompressThms.QuintuplingThm)
        self.tenfoldcompression.triggered.connect(alg.CompressThms.TenfoldCompressionThm)

        self.quartile.triggered.connect(alg.SectionThms.QuartileThm)
        self.NineEqualparts.triggered.connect(alg.SectionThms.NineEqualPartsThm)

        self.AIcutout.triggered.connect(alg.CutOutThms.AIcutoutThm)
        self.bgmean.triggered.connect(alg.CutOutThms.BgMeanThm)
        self.imageSynthesis.triggered.connect(alg.CutOutThms.ImageSynthesisThm)
```

and look the code at `def OpenFile(self)` in algorithm.py, and self.plc at the last line
The problem is the self.plc

```py
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from PyQt5 import QtGui
from PyQt5 import QtCore
import main as m
import cv2

class FileAlgoriThms:
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(FileAlgoriThms, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def OpenFile(self):
        global height, width, nframes, image, bytesPerLine, filename, imgGray, orimg, imgRGB

        filename, filetype = QtWidgets.QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(None, "OpenFile", "./inputImgs", "All Files(*);;Text Files(*.png);;Text Files(*.jpg)")
        orimg = cv2.imread(filename)
        imgGray = cv2.cvtColor(orimg, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        imgRGB = cv2.cvtColor(orimg, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
        height, width, nframes, = imgRGB.shape
        totalBytes = imgRGB.nbytes
        bytesPerLine = int(totalBytes / height)
        img_Lab = QtGui.QImage(imgRGB, width, height, bytesPerLine, QtGui.QImage.Format_RGB888)
        self.pic = QtGui.QPixmap(img_Lab).scaled(width, height)
```

An error occurred when I run the main.py module and trigger event alg.FileAlgoriThms.OpenFile

The Error information:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Galois/Code/imgprocessing/algorithm.py", line 22, in OpenFile
    self.pic = QtGui.QPixmap(img_Lab).scaled(width, height)
AttributeError: 'bool' object has no attribute 'pic'
```

[image]

Comment: the project link: https://github.com/EvaGalois/LinsImgPro

Comment: error can means you assigned `self = True` somewhere. Or maybe you runs `FileAlgoriThms.OpenFile(some_boolean_value)`

Comment: If you want to use `self.` in `OpenFile` then first yoou should create instance of `FileAlgoriThms`  - `fa = arg.FileAlgoriThms()`  and later you should use this instance `fa.OpenFile` when you assign to triggers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
def menuEvent(self):
    file_algorithms = alg.FileAlgoriThms()  # first instantiate object from class
    self.open.triggered.connect(file_algorithms.OpenFile)  # then you can dereference an instance method.
```

Comment: Thank you! It's a very useful answer, 
However, I don't know why there is no error report and no effect. Finally, I used:```self.open.triggered.connect(lambda:file_algorithms.OpenFile())```